# Problem with VMware workstation after installing gns3 "Virtual Ethernet failed"

Tags: networking, vmware

My VMware Workstation was working correctly. Now after I installed `gns3` and configured it to use one of my virtual machines, I get this error when I launch the service with `/etc/init.d/vmware start`:

```
Starting VMware services:
Virtual machine monitor                                          done 
Virtual machine communication interface                          done
VM communication interface socket family                         done
Blocking file system                                             done
Virtual ethernet                                                 failed
VMware Authentication Daemon                                     done
```

And I can't use `bridge mode` any more in my virtual machines.

I can fix this by opening `gns3` and going to **Edit > Preferences > VMware > Network** and clicking on the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button. But when I have to reconfigure it again By clicking on the <kbd>Configure</kbd> button, the problem comes back.

[image: VMware preferences dialog]

I am using `gns3` version `1.5.4` and VMware Workstation version `12.5.0 build-4352439`

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for your answers.